# Mp3 file manipulation

Tags: python, mp3

I'm trying to accelerate the speed of a mp3 file. I'm currently using python on a Mac. I'm not very familiar with this kind of thing, so far I have learned how to read an mp3 file and get it's frame headers, but this is the first time I'm processing audio. So I need some help here.
Does anyone knows some python library to help me? Also can somebody explain me what do I have to do/learn to accomplish that?
I'm really looking for some out of the box solution, but in case there are none, I'm willing to learn and do it myself.

Many thanks!

Comment: By how much do you want to change the speed?  You'd have a very limited choice, but for some speed changes you could just change the sampling frequency in the tag.

Comment: Well, i was looking for something between 1.2 to 1.5 times. I'll try to d that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for manipulation of audio stream you can use http://pymedia.org/tut/, its powerful and yes it cross platform also. If you using linux then gstreamer also a good option.

Comment: pymedia is under GPL2, do you know anything else? 
Would you know what do I have to learn to build what I want?

Comment: give a try with pyo http://code.google.com/p/pyo/ or http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyaudiere/